# Order by array of objects in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

I am getting results from the database in the below format. Now I want to order by on current price column. How can I achieve this?

I already tried this one
$query = $query->orderBy('product_prices.*.current_price', 'desc');

But it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you in advance.

```
[product_prices] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [reference_id] => 616d22af66913e27424bf052
                        [type] => COD
                        [currency] => PHP
                        [amount] => 150
                        [base_price] => 150
                        [tax] => 0
                        [branch_id] => 
                        [current_price] => 150
                        [sale_price] => 0
                        [updated_at] => 2021-11-18 16:11:54
                        [created_at] => 2021-11-18 16:11:54
                        [_id] => 61960acabe2c196446261240
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [reference_id] => 616d22af66913e27424bf052
                        [type] => COD
                        [currency] => PHP
                        [amount] => 150
                        [base_price] => 150
                        [tax] => 0
                        [branch_id] => 
                        [current_price] => 150
                        [sale_price] => 0
                        [updated_at] => 2021-11-18 16:11:54
                        [created_at] => 2021-11-18 16:11:54
                        [_id] => 61960acac5f3aa517b0ac821
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [reference_id] => 616d22af66913e27424bf052
                        [type] => COD
                        [currency] => PHP
                        [amount] => 150
                        [base_price] => 150
                        [tax] => 0
                        [branch_id] => 6141bd9cecd9d04835427112
                        [current_price] => 150
                        [sale_price] => 0
                        [updated_at] => 2021-11-18 16:11:54
                        [created_at] => 2021-11-18 16:11:54
                        [_id] => 61960aca4eb7ca5568776c26
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [reference_id] => 616d22af66913e27424bf052
                        [type] => COD
                        [currency] => PHP
                        [amount] => 150
                        [base_price] => 150
                        [tax] => 0
                        [branch_id] => 6141bd9cecd9d04835427112
                        [current_price] => 150
                        [sale_price] => 0
                        [updated_at] => 2021-11-18 16:11:54
                        [created_at] => 2021-11-18 16:11:54
                        [_id] => 61960acac5f3aa517b0ac822
                    )

            )
```

Comment: Post your query with relationships.

Comment: Is it okay to view it here? https://pastebin.com/P98nun0z

Comment: I saved "product_prices" as field in my products collection

Comment: Why are you using `*` in orderBy?? Try just `$query = $query->orderBy('product_prices.current_price', 'desc');`

Comment: I just thought that in that way I can access all elements by using it. My experimental code before was "product_prices.0.current_price" and it work but in the first element only.

Comment: Try without `*` I just updated my previous comment.

Comment: Already tried it, but it's not working as I expected. I'm trying to access a value in an array of objects so it seems that it  'product_prices.current_price' is not pointing at the right value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239385/discussion-between-yash-parekh-and-robert-capistrano).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your array is in the variable `$products`.
Do:

```
$products = collect($products)->sortByDesc('current_price');
```

And your products will be sorted in descending order according to the `current_price`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I will try it to my current code.